# Copying TimeShift bkp from HDD to HDD maxed my OS SSD to 0 bytes free and bricked it. Need a fail-safe way to copy without compromising the OS SSD

Tags: transfer, snapshot, timeshift

The factors involved:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS running on an SSD /sdb2 119GB with 72GB of free space
- File to transfer: 44.8GB TimeShift protected and locked snapshot
- Source of folder: 4TB internal HDD with 627GB free
- Destination folder: 4TB external HDD with 990 GB free

I’ve been creating TimeShift restore points on a 4TB internal media disk for several years. I’ve never had to restore one until today’s mishap, but the process of backing them up has never caused me trouble until now.

Prior attempts to copy those snapshots to an external 4TB backup disk have always gone smoothly using the terminal commands cited below. Until today.

After generating the latest snapshot this afternoon to preserve my latest application configurations, I used my usual command line method to transfer the locked and protected TimeShift folder from my 4TB internal disk to a USB-connected 4TB external HDD with 990 GB free.

In the past I’ve performed this command in two stages - first purging the prior backup from the external device using this expression:

```
sudo mkdir empty_dir
sudo rsync -a --delete empty_dir/ /[location of backup on external]
```

After which the empty folders can be purged from Nautilus.

I’ve also tried performing this task in the GUI by launching ‘`sudo nautilus`’ and shift+deleting the old backup folder in the resulting window to bypass the trash due to the large size of the snapshot. That seems to still generate a list of errors in the terminal so I stick to the command line expressions above instead. Today I opted for the sudo nautilus method.

One the locked and protected old folder is successfully deleted, I use the command below to create a backup of the latest TimeShift snapshots on my external drive:

```
sudo cp -R sourcepath destinationpath
```

Though some Google searching suggests that I might have more success using the rsync command below with progress bar stats to preserve symlinks and file permissions as well:

```
sudo rsync -aHAXS --info=progress2 sourcepath destinationpath
```

By either method, I have one copy of my Ubuntu OS configuration saved locally on the internal media disk and another fail-safe on a disconnected external HDD.

Today when I attempted to perform the final copy command, the terminal returned a flood of “NOT ENOUGH DISK SPACE” errors.

I checked each disk - the internal and external media drives still had hundreds of GB free. But mysteriously, the local Ubuntu OS SSD was now full with 0 bytes free.

Rebooting bricked the computer. It would hang displaying messages like:

```
/dev/sdb2: clean, 1394377/7299072 files, 29169664/29173760 blocks
```

Or just hang on the hardware manufacturer’s HP logo.

No amount of boot recovery, disk checking, DPKG repair, or FSCK all filesystems from the manufacturer’s boot menu had any effect. The issue was that, for some reason, my OS partition suddenly had 0 bytes free.

To resolve this, I booted to a rescue Ubuntu Live USB I keep on hand.

I installed TimeShift from a Live Session, mounted the disk with the snapshot, and restored it. TimeShift indicated that errors were encountered during restore. Checking the disk in Nautilus, the OS partition still showed 0 bytes free. Booting resulted in the same hanging state.

I next restored an older snapshot in case the latest was corrupted. Same result.

So then I got wise. I launched GParted from the LiveUSB, unmounted the OS partition, and formatted it to start clean and eliminate the 0 bytes available issue.

Then I ran TimeShift once more and restored the latest snapshot (which is the one I really need as it contains all the configurations needed for me to work from home tomorrow morning and all through my work week.)

Another reboot and it was a huge success! All my applications and their respective configurations were restored and everything worked perfectly!

So my question - how can I safely transfer my latest 44.8GB TimeShift snapshot to my external disk without (what I presume is caching) hyperinflating and maxing out the disk space of the OS partition which is neither the source nor the destination of the snapshot?

I’d hate to brick my PC a second time. It’s critical that I don’t lose work hours over this. Working from home is critical to my health, safety, and wellness. I just want to safely back up the latest OS configuration I’ve worked so hard to construct with all the tools I need to do my job.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: The simplest option would be to grab a bootable USB/DVD, boot the machine from there, mount your SSD and external disk (if they're not automatically picked up) and move the file(s). From there, the machine should boot properly again ...

Comment: I tried drafting a reply but exceeded the character limit. Let me try posting this in 3 parts…

PART 1:
I appreciate such a quick response! So do I understand you correctly that, by booting to my Live USB, I effectively rule out the caching or whatever issue was maxing out the disk space on my SSD? I'm puzzled by what was causing that error as previous transfers went flawlessly. 

As I said, the Ubuntu file system SSD was neither the source nor the destination path for the transfer, so I'm confused why its disk space maxed out when I performed the cp command.

Comment: PART 2:

But if you're stating that, by booting to the flash drive, I can mount my internal 4TB HDD which contains the TimeShift snapshot, and then mount the external HDD as the destination, that the task would rule out negatively impacting my precious SSD OS partition, then I'm absolutely willing to give that a try.

Comment: PART 3:

If you can confirm that what I've stated above is correct in interpreting your response, then am I also correct that switching my command from:

`sudo cp -R sourcepath destinationpath`

to:

`sudo rsync -aHAXS --info=progress2 sourcepath destinationpath`

would yield a more productive transfer, with progress bar and the preservation of symlinks and file permissions? Those sound like important properties to preserve for a TimeShift snapshot, and the progress bar would be a great bonus.

Let me know. And thanks again for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

I took Matigo's kind advice and booted to my Live USB, then mounted both the internal and external HDDs, verified the paths to each, and successfully mirrored the protected timeshift folder by running the following command:

```
sudo rsync -aHAXS --info=progress2 sourcepath destinationpath
```

After it completed I verified the transfer and booted my system back to its normal state without any issue.

Thank you so much!